# Visualizing Wheatstone bridges using CircuiTikz

Tags: circuitikz

I want to visualize a [Wheatstone bridge configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge) in LaTeX using the [CircuiTikz package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf).

I want result similar to [this one on Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge#/media/File:Wheatstonebridge.svg) -- what do I need to consider to get a correct rendering?

*Note:* This question was answered Q&A-style and therefore does not display a lack of research effort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use visualize it like this:

[image: Example Wheatstone bridge rendering using CircuiTikz]

using this code (which you can simply compile using `pdflatex`):

```latex
% tikzpic.tex
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,americancurrents,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

%%% Coordinate definitions: %%%
% Position of the bridge (top upper corner)
\def\x{6}
\def\y{6}
% Size of the bridge
\def\dx{3}
\def\dy{3}

\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
  % Voltage source
  \draw (0,0) to [V, l_=5<\volt>]
  (0, \y) to (\x, \y)
  % Left half bridge
  to [R, l_=350<\ohm>, *-*] (\x-\dx,\y-\dy) % Top left resistor
  to [R, l_=350<\ohm>, -*] (\x,\y-2*\dy);  % Bottom left resistor
  % Right half bridge
  \draw (\x,\y)
  to [R, l_=350<\ohm>, -*] (\x+\dx, \y-\dy) % Top right resistor
  to [R, l_=350<\ohm>, -*] (\x,\y-2*\dy)  % Bottom left resistor
  % Draw connection to (-) terminal of voltage source
  to (\x, 0) to (0,0);

  % Draw voltmeter
  \draw (\x-\dx, \y-\dy) to [voltmeter] (\x+\dx, \y-\dy);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the resistance and voltage values are shown in this example. When doing so, ensure you are using the CircuiTikz [siunitx](http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) integration to properly render the units.

For example, use `5<\milli\volts>` instead of `$5mV$` or similar -- the latter would cause improper spacing being rendered between the value and the unit.

In order to place the labels on the opposite side of the element, use `l_` instead of `l_` or vice versa. You can also use `v` to place a text on the other side.

Another important aspect is to ensure all connections of more than 2 wires are rendered as a black dot in order to avoid ambiguities whether the wires are connected. This can be done using the `-*` style (and similar, like `*-*`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks ;-) So far I've only been active on the main SO site, but I've got too many TeX solution I need to get published!