# Wheatstone bridge scheme using CircuiTikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I tried making Wheatstone bridge scheme in LaTeX, but here is what I came up with so far:

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to (8,0);
    \draw (0,0) to (0,2);
    \draw (0,2) to [battery1] (8,2);
    \draw (8,0) to (8,2);
    \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (1pt) node[anchor=north]{A};
    \filldraw[black] (4,1) circle (1pt) node[anchor=north]{B};
    \filldraw[black] (8,0) circle (1pt) node[anchor=north]{C};
    \filldraw[black] (3,0) circle (1pt) node[anchor=north]{D};
\end{circuitikz}
```

I posted a picture how I would like it to be. Thanks for your help! :)

[image: Wheatstone bridge scheme]

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265672/visualizing-wheatstone-bridges-using-circuitikz or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540792/38080 can help?

Comment: I would have used an [american potentiometer] at D.  Yes, you are running a probe over some resistive surface, but that is precisely what a potentiometer does.

Answer (score 4):

A starting point:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) 
        node[circ, label={left:$A$}]{}
        to 
        (0,3.5)
        to[battery2] 
        (6,3.5)
        to 
        (6,0)
        node[circ, label={right:$C$}]{};
    \draw (0,0) 
        to 
        node[currarrow, label={above right:$R_1$}] {} 
        (2.5,0)
        node[circ, label={below right:$D$}]{}
        to 
        node[currarrow, label={above right:$R_2$}]{} 
        (6,0);
    \draw (0,0) 
        to[R=$R_3$, i_>=\null] 
        (3,2)
        node[circ, label={above:$B$}]{}
        to[R=$R_4$, i>_=\null] 
        (6,0);
    \draw (2.5,0) 
        to[out=90, in=270] 
        node[circle, draw, thick, fill=white] {$G$} 
        node[currarrow, sloped, pos=0.8]{} 
        (3,2);
        
    \draw (0,-0.25) -- ++(0,-0.5) 
        (2.5,-0.25) -- ++(0,-0.5) 
        (6,-0.25) -- ++(0,-0.5);
    \draw[<->] (0,-0.5) -- node[below] {$l_1$} (2.5,-0.5);
    \draw[<->] (2.5,-0.5) -- node[below] {$l_2$} (6,-0.5);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]